# How to the get UIViewController which presented a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have

```
NAVIGATIONController A -> ViewController A -> ViewController B
                                                  |
                                                  | (modal)
                                                  | 
                                                 \ /
                                                  '
                                         NAVIGATIONController B -> ViewController C
```

How do I go back to ViewController A from C?

When I am in ViewController C, I tried to print the different controller values:

```
print(self.navigationController) //NAVIGATIONController B
print(self.navigationController?.presentingViewController) //UINavigationController (not sure what this is? It is not one of my classes)
print(self.navigationController?.presentedViewController) //nil
print(self.presentingViewController) //The same UINavigationController (still not sure...)
print(self.presentedViewController) //nil
```

I know how to go back to MyViewController B from MyViewController C, with this line `self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, nil)` but I am asking to go from C to A :-)

How do I even have access to what is before NAVIGATIONController B?

Comment: If you want to go back from one view controller to a previously displayed one, look into using "unwind segues" - that way you don't have to encode the knowledge of your presentation hierarchy into ViewController C.

Comment: It is iOS9 only, I need iOS8 support.

Comment: How do I use popToView from Controller C? I can only dismiss to Controller B but then I have no control to go to A (all that from C). I don't want to create a flag on B that I set to true when presenting NavController B (and so view C) and checking on viewDidAppear if the flag is activated... It doesn't look clean.

Comment: dismiss ViewController C in  ViewController B and in that completion pop ViewController B

Comment: This is my entire question actually... How do I even get access to what is before Navigation B? All my `print` show either the Navigation B or nil

Comment: @BabyAzerty unwind segues were introduced with iOS 6. only some newer API is iOS 9 specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UINavigationController` from `self.navigationController?.presentingViewController` should be your "NAVIGATIONController A".

What you should be able to do from C is get "NAVIGATIONController A" with `self.navigationController?.presentingViewController` and call `popToRootViewController` (do this unanimated).

Then dismiss "ViewController C" (and its nav controller) with `self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, nil)`.

This way, when "ViewController C" is dismissed, the top level nav controller will already be showing "ViewController A".

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly :) Here is my full code:
`(self.navigationController?.presentingViewController as! UINavigationController).popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)`

`self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Great Answer ! and Thanks for posting your implemented answer too

Answer (score 1):

in BScene's viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.noti), name: "popAndDismiss", object: nil)
}
func noti() {
        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

in CScene's buttonAction:

```
@IBAction func click(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("popAndDismiss", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
    navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use popToViewController.

[self.navigationController popToViewController:yourviewcontroller animated:YES];

This will pop the viewcontrollers until it reach yourviewcontroller.
Hope this will help.